# JSON.stringify time shift

Tags: javascript, json, date

In chrome developer tools in console following line:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(2018,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

gives this output:

```
""2017-12-31T23:00:00.000Z""
```

but this line:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(1800,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

gives

```
""1799-12-31T22:36:00.000Z""
```

Why is so? I live in central Europe so i understand 1 hour saving time shift (winter time) but why also 24 minutes in second case?

Comment: It is a recent update designed to better reflect historical time. There was no such thing as a "time zone" back in 1799.

Comment: Also it doesn't have anything at all to do with `JSON.stringify()`. It's behavior of the Date API.